# Association between Router and Coordinator in Zigbee protocol

Tags: zigbee

In Zigbee protocol, Router tries to associate to Coordinator ?

For example, Router or coordinator scan to find each other and send a beacon/beacon request, after then send a association request .. ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: I'd recommend searching the ZigBee website for a description of how nodes associate to the network.  IIRC, a node wanting to join sends a Beacon Request, receives a Beacon Response from Coordinators and Routers on that channel, and then sends an Association Request to the nearest (best signal quality) node with matching settings (PAN ID, ZigBee Stack version, etc.).